# Does google libphonenumber API provide CITY name based on the area code?

Tags: java, phone-number, libphonenumber

I am working on **google libphonenumber** to get the phone number's information. I was able to pull the State & country name. But I am unable to get the CITY name. Does the google API provide CITY name as well ?

Please advice thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean just by area code, most area codes span many cities.  You need to get down to the exchange for the question to make sense.

Comment: @Max Maybe you didn't understand me in right way, But I found this library called geocoder which gives the geo location of incoming phone number. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link to the library?

Answer (score 2):

> Does Google's `libphonenumber` API provide **city** names based on the area code?

Yes - but only if its internal geocoding database contains that information. Some US phone numbers are entirely non-geographic (like `1-800` numbers) and for many others the database just doesn't have that information.

Also, `libphonenumber`'s geo lookup only returns single `string` values: it does not return structured data, like a class with city, state, county, and zip code fields. And the format of the returned string value varies considerably - limiting its uses in any automated system as it necessarily requires a human user to interpret the data.

For example, using the current `libphonenumber` (as of December 2021, that's version `8.12.38`), I get the following results for these fictitious, but valid, numbers:

- `1-800-333-4567`

  - This is a non-geographic "1-800" (toll-free) number.
  - `libphonenumber`'s lookup returns the string `"United States"`.
- `1-201-200-0000`

  - The is is a US phone number in area code 201 for New Jersey.
  - `libphonenumber`'s lookup returns the string `"Jersey City, NJ"`.

    - It resolved it to a city and state, giving the state's abbreviation.
- `1-425-666-9999`

  - This is (almost) my own personal phone number which I got from a T-Mobile store in Redmond, WA.
  - But `libphonenumber`'s lookup returns only the imprecise string `"Washington State"` with no city name or similar. It's curious that it returned the full US state name instead of the `"WA"` abbreviation.

---

Remember, as with any in-proc "*offline*" geolocation database, data will inevitably go stale and inaccurate. Also, in the US at least, it's impossible to differentiate between mobile-phone numbers and landline numbers, and the area-code of someone's mobile-phone number is completely detached from the phone subscriber's actual physical location (it's usually the area-code of the AT&T / T-Mobile / Sprint store where they initially signed-up for service, [even if they subsequently move across the country](https://xkcd.com/1129/)).

Anyway, here's how you use the `PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder` class:

#### Java:

```java
static string lookupNumber( string phoneNumber ) {
    
    PhoneNumber parsed = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().parse( phoneNumber, /*defaultRegion:*/ "US" );

    return PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder.getInstance().getDescriptionForNumber( parsed, Locale.ENGLISH );
}

lookupNumber( "1-800-333-4567" ) // "United States"

lookupNumber( "+12012000000" ) // "Jersey City, NJ"

lookupNumber( "+14256669999" ) // "Washington State"
```

#### C#

```cs
static String LookupNumber( string phoneNumber ) {
    
    PhoneNumber parsed = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance().Parse( phoneNumber, defaultRegion: "US" );

    return PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder.GetInstance().GetDescriptionForNumber( parsed, Locale.English );
}

LookupNumber( "1-800-333-4567" ) // "United States"

LookupNumber( "+12012000000" ) // "Jersey City, NJ"

LookupNumber( "+14256669999" ) // "Washington State"
```